# Problem importing Civi Volunteer Needs

Tags: import, civivolunteer

We are working importing Volunteer Needs for various Volunteer Projects via the API csv Extension. When we load the interface, select the entity 'VolunteerNeed' and select file. When we hit continue we get the following:

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   CRM_Volunteer_DAO_Project::indices() in
>   /home/<>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/v3/Generic/Getunique.php
>   on line 44 civicrm_api3_generic_getunique()
>   wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php:97
>   invoke() wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php:168
>   runRequest() wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php:99
>   runSafe() wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php:43
>   civicrm_api3()
>   wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/nz.co.fuzion.csvimport/CRM/Csvimport/Import/Form/MapFieldBaseClass.php:126
>   preProcess() wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php:585
>   buildForm()
>   wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php:92
>   perform()
>   wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php:203
>   handle()
>   wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php:103
>   handle()
>   wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php:349 run()
>   wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:311 runItem()
>   wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:85
>   _invoke() wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:52 invoke() wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:1392 invoke()
>   wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:286 apply_filters()
>   wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:310 do_action()
>   wp-includes/plugin.php:465 do_action() wp-admin/admin.php:253

We have used the extension to import other entities with no issues. The site is running WP 5.2.4, CiviCRM 5.13.4, CiviVolunteer v4.7.31-2.3.1 & CSV GUI Import to api  v 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

That error suggests that the entity (volunteer project) defined in the civivolunteer extension is "incomplete", i.e that it's missing an indices method.